# Pass the previously assigned pointer value to a loop

Tags: c++, pointers

I've got a string pointer `string* ifxPtr;`, what I'm trying to do is to set this pointer to point to the user input and then loop through each character of it.

```
string* ifxPtr;

void Expression::GetInfix(string data) // This method runs first and it's setting the pointer to point to previously passed user input
{   
   ifxPtr = &data;
   ConvertToPostfix();
}

void Expression::ConvertToPostfix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *ifxPtr->length; i++) // Here's the struggle, compiler is complaining about *ifxPtr with message Cannot apply binary '<' to 'int' and 'unassigned() const'
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `length` is a function and it should be `length()`
2. You
   don't need to deference the pointer if you use `->`
3. The result
   returned from `length()` is `size_t`

Here is what I would use:

```
int length = static_cast<int>((*ifxPtr).length());
```

Comment: I didn't even spot `1`, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

`foo->` is shorthand for `(*foo).`. Don't double up operators, also it should be `length()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ifxPtr->length(); i++)
```

Also, be careful with that design, possibility of running into Undefined Behaviour with a simple mistake is big.

Comment: It's still complaining with the same message.

Comment: @NaughtyNinja I'm assuming you're using `std::string`? Are you sure it's included and are you sure it's not just a warning about comparing a unsigned to a signed int.?

Comment: Yes i am using std::string and no it's not a warning it's an error so it doesn't compile -  Cannot apply binary '<' to 'int' and 'unassigned() const'.

Comment: I edited my answer, it's a function not a member, Justin's answer is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

if you use and *before it means using the value which is pointed by the pointer.

string s,*p;
p=&s;

here *p.lenght() is same as s.length if you want to access through pointer you have to use it like this p->length().